# CBCentralManager peripheral discovery deteriorating after a longer search

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently developing an app that is gonna be used for connecting with BLE devices. Everything works fine for the most part, but I have noticed a weird behaviour from the CBCentralManager class. The longer it runs a search for BLE peripherals, the less often it can actually find the same peripheral (I am talking about discovering advertisement packages).  I have tried some 3rd party apps (BLE scanners etc.), and they can find my peripheral without any problems. It does advertise every X seconds, and the apps can usually find it after 1-3 * X. Here is a very simple implementation of the BLE discovery code that shows the discovery deterioration symptoms:

```
import CoreBluetooth

class BluetoothTestClass: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    
    private let manager: CBCentralManager
    
    override init() {
        self.manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: nil, queue: .main, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:true])
        super.init()
        
        self.manager.delegate = self
    }
    
    func startSearch() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            self.manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey:true,
                                                                    CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:true])
        }
    }
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    }
    
    var peripherals: [CBPeripheral] = []
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        peripherals.append(peripheral)
        print(Date())
    }
}
```

The only thing that I found that helps at this point, is resetting the search every 30 seconds, then the search results are pretty close to what I can see in the 3rd party scanner apps (peripheral found after 1-3 * X seconds).

Any leads, ideas and even breadcrumbs on this topic will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your code never calls `startSearch` and you don't properly wait for the `.poweredOn` state before starting to scan.  It helps if you post a [mcve] rather than not-your-actual-code. One thing I note is that continually appending discovered peripherals to an array isn't a very useful strategy; you would typically want to store them in a dictionary so that you can keep track of the visible peripherals and time them out. That aside, I can't see anything in the code shown that would cause problems. Using `asyncAfter` is a bit of a code smell, though.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the discovery rate deteriorates as the search continues is likely due to the internal state of the `CBCentralManager` object. Over time, it may build up internal data structures or allocate more memory, impacting its performance.

Resetting the search every 30 seconds can help to alleviate this issue, as it discards the internal state of the `CBCentralManager` and starts with a clean slate. Additionally, you may consider using a different `dispatch queue` for running the BLE discovery code.

Another thing that you may consider is limiting the duration of the scan, as the longer, the scan continues, the more the discovery performance may deteriorate. You can set the scan timeout option when calling `scanForPeripherals(withServices:options:)` to limit the duration of the scan.